# relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_PyRuntime' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-3.7

Getting following link error while building a library in Python3.7 on 64bit machine.

```
 /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.a(ceval.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_PyRuntime' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

On that same machine, if I install a miniconda https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html [Py 3.8 for 64bit], the library installs fine in that conda environment without any error.

I tried buildingin Py3.7 by adding

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC"
```

However, the error persists for python3.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Option 1

Build/Compile Python using `--enable-shared`

### Option 2

Error suggests using `-fPIC`
So one can choose

```
CFLAGS=-fPIC
```

in the make install or [equivalent build step]

Both should work.

Comment: `cxxflags=-fPIC cflags=-fPIC` how to use this couldn't understand. like this: `export cflags=-fPIC ; export cxxflags=-fPIC; make altinstall` ?

Comment: figured out:
`export CFLAGS=-fPIC ; ./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-optimizations`
`make altinstall`
thanks.